# PHP ignoring cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm making a mysqli query with limits that are set via $_COOKIE.

The way it works is that I send the query with the URL and PHP turns that into a cookie so the user does not see any change in their URL.

Then PHP reads the cookie and makes the query, and then clears the cookie so that the user does not get mixed-up limits on other queries.

It worked fine until I had to change servers, from one hosting provider to another, and now its not working and I have already build upon this mechanism.

I'm guessing maybe the PHP version matters or some php.ini config is different that makes the original server work, but not the second one. Sadly, I cant just finish the project on the first one. Any clues or suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
// GET LIMIT, PLACE IT ON A COOKIE
if (isset($_GET['l'])) {
    $cookie_name = "limit";
    $cookie_value = $_GET['l'];
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 1), "/bk"); // 86400 = 1 day
    header('Location:admin.php');
    die;
}
```

Then, in "admin.php":

```
// GET COOKIE VALUE, DELETE COOKIE
if(isset($_COOKIE['limit'])) {
    $limit = $_COOKIE['limit'];
    setcookie("limit", '', time() -3600, "/bk"); 
} else {
    $limit = 0;
}
```

Then I do my query.

In the last server, for example, if the limit was 10 - by the end of the second block of code, $limit would equal 10 - but in this new server, $limit is 0. I did some testing, and second If is working, it does get triggered but by the end of the if, $limit equals 0.

Help?

Comment: You're restricting the cookie to the `/bk` path. Are the two scripts involved hosted at such path?

Comment: Yes Sr. they both are. - Thank you!

Comment: A: use the domain, not a folder

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the `setcookie(..)` line ?

like setting the cookie without specifying a domain or setting a global one

also I think some `var_dump($_COOKIE)` at the beginning of "admin.php" can help.

Comment: Hi @Hossam. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a typical forum, and this would be best suited as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I did. 

The problem seems to be that in the second IF the set cookie instruction somehow is triggering faster than when the variable is set. 

And, how would a dump help? If I dump the cookie value, how then would I get to the point of reading it to get the $limit variable value???

Comment: Hi @hd , Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to make a comment. If I had, I would have commented rather than replied.

Comment: @Sopo Lilo : I bebieve you can comment the second setcookie for a while, var_dump the $_COOKIE at the beginning of the admin.php to see wheather the problem is in the first setcookie or in reading it.

Comment: @SopoLilo : all I mean here is that we can reduce the scope where we think the problem in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone can explain why...

I changed the limit variable on my URL "l" for "lim" and that made the difference.

The cookie is getting written and read without a problem. I ignore why, somehow when the URL read page.php?l=10 the $_GET order was getting skipped.

I changed it to page.php?lim=10 and now it works as it did on the first server.

Any comments as to why would be appreciated.